# plugin incompatible with the new build found: firebase services ¿Puedo actualizar?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, plugin, actualizacion

Actualmente Android Studio me está pidiendo una actualización, pero al final me dice : plugin incompatible with the new build found: firebase services.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Puedo actualizar sin problemas? ¿Tendría que hacer algo después de la actualización? ¿Mejor espero? ¿Estoy loco?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿como hiciste para actualizar? yo le he dado a "Update and Restart" pasa al proceso de descarga, reinicia android studio pero no hay cambio alguno, se queda en la versión 3.6.3 (la que utilizo actualmente). He leído en la versión ingles de stackoverflow que se debe ir a: **Configure -> plugins -> Buscar el plugin de Firebase Service y actualizarlo (en caso de que sea posible) o des-habilitarlo**. Pero, ¿si no me deja habilitar después del update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguien me había dado una respuesta pero parece que la eliminó o se eliminó sola.

Pues no pasa nada, actualicé y todo anduvo correcto, Firebase Services no me dio problema alguno.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo mensaje que te aparecía a ti y lo actualicé. Los complementos de Firebase están incluidos. No deberias tener problemas al actualizar y reiniciar.